# How i can use a router-link in kendo grid (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vue-router

How i can use `<router-link to="/detail/1">Details</router-link>` with Kendo Grid?
I want use the standard logic of a normal link in the grid, with no reload of the full page on click. I have try to use `router-link` inside the grid with a template but it's doesn't work. Also no error in available in console.

[Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3tyxxg-b1vk7m)

**Update 24 October 2018**

Kendo Grid for Vue is initializing a plain Kendo Grid widget for jQuery.
Thus, all templates are evaluated runtime and possible routes cannot be evaluated afterwards or the router-link elements to be resolved.

If you have the same problem Vote for this suggestion
[vue native implementation](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/33871774-vue-native)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with kendo grid native

Comment: @DevduttSharma [kendo vue grid native](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-native/) is available

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you cannot use router-link inside a kendo template. But I thought I would offer an alternative way to achieve the same result.

You can redirect to the new page [using the programmatic way](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) by calling `router.push({ path:`/detail/${id}`})`.

Replace the template with a [command](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columns.command.click) that implements a click event, and call `route.push` from there.

I have updated [your example on slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3tyxxg-vscp56) with a working example.

**Kendo Grid with command col**

```
<kendo-grid ref="grid"
            :height="550"
            :data-source-ref="'datasource1'"
            :sortable="true">
    <kendo-grid-column :field="'ProductID'"
                       :title="'Product ID'"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column :field="'ProductName'"
                       :title="'Product Name'"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column :field="'Link'" :template="linkTemplate1"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column :command="detailsLink"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**Command array in the data object.**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vueapp',
    router,
    data () {
        return {
          linkTemplate1: "<a href='/detail/#:ProductID#' class='k-button'>Link</a>",
          detailsLink: [{ 
            name: "details",
            click: function(e) {
              // prevent page scroll position change
              e.preventDefault();
              var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
              // get the data bound to the current table row
              var data = this.dataItem(tr);
              // redirect to new page
              router.push({ path: `/detail/${data.ProductID}` })
            },// template must include k-grid-[command name]
            template: "<a class='k-button k-grid-details'>TEST</a>"
          }]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: this answer predates the release of kendo vue native. it is for the old jquery wrapper kendo vue.js controls.